# Sending an array to index via Algolia's Laravel Search Framework

Tags: laravel, algolia

I'm having some difficulty sending an array to be indexed in Algolia because I have to encode it to save it to the database first.

```
$algoliaAgent = AlgoliaAgent::firstOrCreate([
    'FirstName' => $item->FirstName,
    'LastName' => $item->LastName,
    'AgentRecId' => $item->AgentRecId,
    'Style' => json_encode(explode(',', $item->Style))
]);

$algoliaAgent->pushToIndex();
```

The resulting index in Algolia looks like this:

```
"[\"value1\",\"value2\",\"value3\"]"
```

Is there a method to decode the value before sending it to Algolia?

Comment: Using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) methods.

Also, see the [Laravel Scout documenation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout#configuring-searchable-data) for more information about what is indexed.

> By default, the entire toArray form of a given model will be persisted to its search index. If you would like to customize the data that is synchronized to the search index, you may override the toSearchableArray method on the model:

Comment: Thanks Erik but I'm still in 5.2.  But your answer made me think about modifying the pushToIndex method in the source code.

Comment: Oh okay, what is the problem exactly that you are encountering? Are the extra escape characters the problem you are referring to? Or because it is not an associative array?

Comment: This was the error I was getting if I didn't encode :  ErrorException preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array.   Nope, it isn't an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was to modify the pushToIndex() method to intercept the the loop that sends the object to Algolia.

Something like this:
    public function pushToIndex()
    {
        /** @var \AlgoliaSearch\Laravel\ModelHelper $modelHelper */
        $modelHelper = App::make('\AlgoliaSearch\Laravel\ModelHelper');

```
    $indices = $modelHelper->getIndices($this);

    /** @var \AlgoliaSearch\Index $index */
    foreach ($indices as $index) {

        if ($modelHelper->indexOnly($this, $index->indexName)) {

            $temp = $this->getAlgoliaRecordDefault($index->indexName);

            $temp['Style'] = $this->castArray($temp['Style']);

            //$index->addObject($this->getAlgoliaRecordDefault($index->indexName));
            $index->addObject($temp);

        }
    }
}

public function castArray($raw) {
    $arrayString = '';
    if(is_string($raw)) {
        $arrayString = explode(",",$raw);
    }
    return $arrayString;
}
```